# Apply water mask to a raster layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector, masking

I have a vector polygon layer which represents water bodies and I have a raster layer (250m pixel NDVI values). What I need is to mask all pixels in a raster layer that intersect my water mask and turn them into NoData.

Since I want to do it in ArcMap, there seems to be a bunch of tools like [set null](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/set-null.htm) and [con](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm), but they work only with raster data. On the other hand, [extract by mask](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm) does the opposite to what I need: it masks everything BUT the mask.

So my question is: is there a (best) way to apply a vector mask to a raster layer in ArcMap? And if no - how do I do it through rasterizing vector data, taking into account the resolution of the target layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you have access to the spatial analyst extension license.

You can rasterize your polygons with [Polygon to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000030000000), use OID/FID as value field but it doesn't matter what field you use as long as it is numeric, but before you do set your environments [cell size](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w0000001s000000), [output extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000009000000) and [snap raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Snap_Raster/001w0000000m000000/) to your existing NDVI raster. Your polygon raster will now have the same extent and cell size as your existing NDVI raster and cell boundaries will align.

Using [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) with an [IsNull](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000m8000000) statement on the polygon raster set where IsNull is True to NDVI and a constant, -29999 would work, where False. With [SetRasterProperties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015z000000) set the NoData value of the output raster to -29999.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to @Michael Stimson 's method. You can create a polygon which covers your entire area as like AOI. Then clip water polygons with erase tool. After that you will have a big polygon where water bodies are holes. Finally you can use extract by mask tool.